# Watch history won't load fully on youtube app

Tags: youtube

My watch history will no longer load any videos past a certain point and every time I watch a new video it will remove the oldest video in my watch history.

This started happening around January after an update when I was scrolling through my watch history and it suddenly glitched and wouldn't show me any more.I have never deleted my watch history and I have auto delete turned off. I don't understand why youtube started doing this. Is it a setting I accidentally turned on or part of a new update? Or is it that only premium users can see their full watch history?

I've tried deleting storage and cache, restarting my device and going on youtube through chrome. Nothing has worked. Does anyone know a solution to this?

Comment: Also posted on WebApps.SE: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/173734/79784.

Comment: I have YouTube Premium and I just tried scrolling until Nov 2023 in the YouTube app, but I don't think it's related because I couldn't find any statement if the watch history is limited for non-Premium users. However, watch history is saved on the server side, so I don't think it's a specific issue with the YouTube Android app. That said, how many videos can you load in your watch history?